# MultiIndex on both Columns and Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I tried using pd.MultiIndex but it only displays something like this [screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSLLP.png)

Are there other ways to get this result? Here's my the code that I used:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.merge(sad,das, how='outer')
df1.set_index(['parent_category','category','name'], inplace= True)
df1.fillna(value=0)
df1

header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['January','February','March','April','May','June','July'],['Purchased','Sold','Inventory']], names = ['months','header'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=header)
df2
```

Comment: Maybe there is another way, can you add sample data? 3,4 rows from `sad` and `das`. Also [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign new columns names to `df1 columns`, but necessary same length of original columns and Multiindex:

```
df1 = pd.merge(sad,das, how='outer') \
        .set_index(['parent_category','category','name']) \
        .fillna(value=0)

months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July']
items = ['Purchased','Sold','Inventory']

len(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([months,items], names = ['months','header']))
21

len(df1.columns)

df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([months,items], names = ['months','header'])

df1
```